# my Apache version seems to cause THREE.js to render in chrome differently from the way it renders in Firefox

Tags: javascript, apache, google-chrome, three.js, redhat

At my wits end trying to figure out why this is happening:

[image]

Running red hat.  Installed Apache by :yum install httpd (so latest[??] version 2013-04-13)
absolutely no alterations to the original -r57 file downloaded from the three.js site
(the three.js site renders the same file on both browsers without any distortion - so it HAS to be my server but I can't find out why...). I've [restarted/reinstalled/altered the conf] on Apache and rebooted the server but I can't get chrome to render properly.

```
[/home]>/etc/init.d/httpd help
Usage: **/usr/sbin/httpd** [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                       [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                       [-k start|restart|graceful|stop]
                       [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-S]
  ...
[/home]>/usr/sbin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.0.52
Server built:   May 24 2006 11:45:10
[/home]>uname -srvmpio
Linux 2.6.9-42.7.ELsmp #1 SMP Tue Sep 5 18:29:39 EDT 2006 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[/home]
```

**Question(s):
Why is the distortion happening in Chrome on my server?** - it doesn't normally happen - I can't get it to render properly - does anyone have any idea why this is happening? or can suggest something I can try?

Still don't see the question?

- download the zip file yourself from mrdoob.github.io/three.js
- save it on your desktop
- unzip it
- go to the examples folder
- open css3d_periodictable.html in the chrome browser directly
- click on 'helix'
- it will render as a circlular helix when viewed using the chrome browser
  (just as on the [Three.js site](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/css3d_periodictable.html) it renders as a circular helix when viewed using the chrome browser)
- on my server it renders normally -as a circular helix- when viewed using the firefox browser
- BUT on my server (for some inexplicable reason) it renders as an oval helix when viewed using the chrome browser
- see the link for the **pic** of this above (on the first line, below the title), the link leads you to a picture displaying the file in chrome on the left -with a distorted abnormal oval shape- and firefox on the right with the file displaying as it's supposed to.
- **I'm trying to figure out what could be causing this distortion and why it only seems to occur in chrome when I access the file from my server**.

**SOLVED** : upgraded the OS to redhat 5.5 - bit of an "attack souffle with shovel" solution - but it worked.

Comment: the left one is Chrome.. the right one is Firefox.. maybe because of that

Comment: the point is that they should render the same - they do render the same normally on both browsers; try it yourself with this link: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/css3d_periodictable.html

Comment: WebGL is used in conjunction with Three.js - inb4 tangental reply -> Wikipedia - "...The second contributor in terms of commits, Branislav Ulicny... He wanted WebGL renderer capabilities in Three.js to exceed those of CanvasRenderer or SVGRenderer.[9] His major contributions generally involve materials, shaders and post-processing..." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three.js

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You are using different browsers.. the implementation of css3 is still a draft: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp it is not guaranteed that different browsers will render the same.. and as @WestLangley, it is not clear what's your question.